# How I can send mails from Visual Basic with Attachments (PDF)

Tags: vb.net, email-attachments, windows

Why I can't send files more than 4 mb? In my VB App

Comment: This code is already in VB.NET, so what is your problem?

Comment: I must send PDF files, but now i can't

Comment: Do you get any error message? What is the content of your `attachement` textbox? It is a full filename or just a filename relative to the current directory?

Comment: No i don't have, in attachement.textbox is access path

Comment: When i send jpg, txt, exe file it shows in my e-mail but when i send pdf it isn't

Comment: When i'm sending pdf I've got an error Failure sending mail. smtpexception unhandled

Comment: What is the exception message? PDF can be too large or prohibited by the SMTP server.

Comment: PDF is too large what can I do?

Comment: My app accept files in maksimum 3,90 mb what can I do?

Comment: Can you post all the information about the exception you get?

Answer (score 0):

The smtp mail server you are using most likely has a limit on the size email it can accept, maybe 4 mb or less in your case. You should increase that limit on the mail server, or compress the attachment to make the email smaller.